# Rails ActiveModelSerializers - Serializer Not Working When Rendering All CRUD

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

When doing a create or update, I usually write my controllers like this:

```
def update
    if current_user.update(user_params)
        render status: 200, json: {
            message: "Successfully updated user.",
            user: current_user
        }.to_json
    else
        render status: 422, json: {
            errors: current_user.errors
        }
    end
end
```

You can see, I want to pass a custom message along with my user object. But when I do this, it doesn't use the UserSerializer... I tried using This:

```
render status: 200, json: {
    message: "Successfully updated user.",
    user: ActiveModel::Serializer::UserSerializer.new(user)
}.to_json
```

That works... but that causes a problem if there's ever an object that is null... It causes a Rails error.

Is there a better way to handle this without having to spend a ton of time re-writing my dozens of create/update controllers?

Specifically, I'm looking to return JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "message": "Successfully updated user.",
    "user": {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: what serializer version do you use ?

Comment: 0.10 is the version that I am using.

Answer (score 0):

> Tested version `active_model_serializers (0.10.6)` everything works
>   fine, including custom message and user serializer.

```
    render status: 200, json: {
        message: "Successfully updated user.",
        menu: UserSerializer.new(user)
    }.to_json
```

Comment: Thank you for the response, but I really need the top level object like so:

{ "user": { ... }, "message": "Hello" }

And this way gets rid of it. Our existing apps all follow this formatting for pulling the JSON API and we can't go back now. This is the way it was in 0.9.x and we need it to stay consistent.

Comment: this scope work .0.10 also `scope: {user: {message: "Successfully updated user."}}`

Comment: Sorry, this isn't quite what I'm looking for. I've updated my question, that might help explain it better. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @ErickMaynard updated post, make sure yr file name class name is correct !